# Network folder access denied after setting "Allow" permissions to folder for Group

Tags: windows, networking, permissions, shared-folders

The folder `TestProj` is a shared folder at the root of a host server's `E:\` drive. I made a new group called `WebDevGroup` with the user `WebDev` inside it. I assigned `WebDevGroup` the permissions to the `TestProj` folder below. Despite these permissions, I cannot open the folder when logged in as `WebDev`.

How can I [successfully] grant users in `WebDevGroup` `Allow` permissions to specific network folders?

What I Googled & tried:

- I ensured there was not a shared folder in the hierarchy above `TestProj` that I needed to additionally grant `WebDev` access to.

  - (Even so, I still logged into the host server and additionally granted `WebDevGroup` explicit `Allow` permissions to the host server's `E:\` drive anyway, just in case.)
- I logged out/logged into the `WebDev` account multiple times.
- I deleted the local `WebDev` user profile so the PC would rebuild the profile on next login.
- I logged in as `WebDev` on a different PC & attempted to access `TestProj`.
- I ran `gpresult /r /scope:user` (seen below) to confirm `WebDev` was a member of `WebDevGroup`.
- I applied the `Allow` permissions to `WebDev` directly instead of to `WebDevGroup`.
  [image]

Comment: If you're accessing the folder through its share-name, permissions on the share are also required. They are found in the Properties of the share, Sharing tab, Advanced Sharing.

Comment: Gah! I went into the Sharing properties of the share about 5 times and totally missed the `Permissions` button--I was one click away! Thank you @harrymc

Comment: I added it then as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're accessing the folder through its share-name,
permissions on the share are also required.

They are found in the Properties of the share, Sharing tab, Advanced Sharing.

Comment: Note, Microsoft has long recommended that share permissions be always set to "Everyone (Full Control)".  Share permissions are required, but they will always be overridden by filesystem permissions on the directory on disk, so put your permissions logic there, rather than in the Share. Filesystem Permissions are stored on the disk as part of the directory metadata, but share info is stored in the OS (registry) so if you ever tried to restore a servers data disk, you would keep your settings, but share based settings get lost when the OS is rebuilt.